# using self.location and url page values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have the following:

```
$ul.append('<li>' + 
'<a href="setlocale.aspx?returnURL=default.aspx&localesetting=' + 
this.slice(0) + '">' + this.slice(3) + '</a>');
```

Lets say my URL ends with: `/c-577-camping.aspx`

How do I use this value in my jquery? it should change `default.aspx` to `c-577-camping.aspx` and if the website is `www.site.com/c-517-cookers.aspx` then it should append:

`http://www.site.com/c-517-cookers.aspx?setlocale.aspx?returnURL=c-517-cookers.aspx&localesetting=fr-FR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the path, you can use window.location.pathname:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pathname = window.location.pathname;

  $ul.append('<li>' + '<a href="setlocale.aspx?returnURL=' + pathname + '&localesetting=' + this.slice(0) + '">' + this.slice(3) + '</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`location.pathname` includes the slash, so try:

```
'<a href="setlocale.aspx?returnURL='+ location.pathname.replace(/\//g,'') +'&localesetting=' +....
```

If there is a chance the pathname already contains some get parameters, you'll either need to use `encodeURI(location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')`, replacing just the first slash or use `location.pathname.replace(/\//g,'').split('?')[0]` to chop off the parameters.

PS: don't use `window.location.pathname`, there's no need. It is in fact marginally faster not to use `window`, as it is a circular reference to the global (nameless) object.

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
window.location.pathname
```

?

So full code:

```
$ul.append('<li>' + '<a href="setlocale.aspx?returnURL=' + window.location.pathname + '&localesetting=' + this.slice(0) + '">' + this.slice(3) + '</a>');
```